# Regex pattern to replace the second half of the text

Tags: python, regex

My aim: to replace the product with a variable, "newproduct" I have gotten earlier.

I have a text in a word document - Product type: Red button shirt. Here's how the text would look like in the word document.

```
Product type:                      Red. button shirt
```

Note that

1. the space between : and R is a combination of white space, tab in random order and can vary in number of space or tabs. Eg. space\t\tspace or \tspace\t\t\t\tspace.
2. The text "Red button shirt" can be other different words like `Blue. tapered pants high cut` (it has period in the string and it can be any words and it can be any number of words like 2-10words) etc.

How do I get the text Red button shirt? I first isolated the red button shirt word but i could not replace it with a variable, newproduct, that I have set.

```
pattern = r"Product type:[\s.]*.*"
match = None

for p in doc.paragraphs:
    match = re.search(pattern, p.text)
    if match:
        updatedref_text = re.search(r"(?<=Product type: ).*",match.group(0))
        wordsonly = re.search(r"([a-zA-Z+].*)",updatedref_text.group(0))
        updated_text = re.sub(r".*", newproduct, wordsonly.group(0))
        p.text = updated_text
        p.style.font.name = 'Arial'
        p.style.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(10)
```

The output is two of the variable newproduct. Appreciate all the help guys!

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Show the exact text in code markup. Especially since you're asking about how to _match_ that text. Because [if it's your program input, show your exact input](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The indentation of your code is wrong. This code does not compile. Secondly, remove code that is not related to your question. This includes anything related to `doc.paragraphs`, `docx`, ...etc.

Comment: Is it always 3 words or is there an end of line after those words?

Comment: How about: `"Product type:\s*(.*)"`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have input the exact text but I am not too sure if its a code markup. Couldnt find a option for that.

Comment: @trincot I have manually indented. Hope it works now. It was indented in my code but when I paste over, the indentation is gone. The doc.paragraphs shows that i am using the word document and a loop to find the phrase Product type:                      Red. button shirt. Thought it would be relevant in allowing the community understand my issue

Comment: @JonSG it ranges and can be more than 3 words. And there are periods in the string as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the "Product type: " part with all the spacing in a capture group, and then the text of interest in a second capture group, requiring that it ends with a non-white space.

Then replace this with the reproduction of what was captured in the first group, and add the new product text after it, discarding what was captured by the second capture group.

```py
pattern = r"(Product type:\s+)(.*\S)"
newproduct = "My new product"

text = "Product type: \t \t \t\t       Red. button shirt  "
result = re.sub(pattern, fr"\1{newproduct}", text)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
Product type:                     My new product
```

Comment: This is the exact pattern to resolve. Thank you!